# alert if already dropped div is dropped again using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my drag and drop script and it seems to be working like a charm, but what I want to add is if I drop a dragable div on a div that already contains the same div than it should give me an alert that this dragable element already exists or something like that,  in order to achieve this I applied `.prevAll.each()` function to get the id's and compare to the last dropped div. So it compares the id's fine but when I drop the already existing div, it completely jumps the `.prevAll.each()` condition, it alerts its own id like the others but it does not go in the `.prevAll`, why is that?

Summing up what I want is:

1. Edit the approach below to get alert if already existed div is dropped.
2. Or any other approach would also be appreciated if it gives me the same functionality and doesn't affect any other thing, I already tried the `.length` approach its not working.

I hope I was able to explain, Any help would be appreciated, Thank you

```
$(".dragable").draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    live: true,
    revertDuration: 0


    });

$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".dragable",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $item = $(ui.draggable);
    if (!$item.hasClass('clone')) {
    $item = $item.clone().addClass('clone');
    $item.draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon",
        revert: true,
        cursor: "move",
        revertDuration: 0
        });
}
$(this).addClass('has-drop').append($item);
var divIdIs = $(ui.draggable).attr( "id" );
//if($(".droppable:has()"))
/*if($("#"+divIdIs).length>1){
alert("Yeah it does exist");
}*/
$("#"+divIdIs).prevAll().each(function() {
    var upperDiv = $(this).attr('id');
    /*var tes=$("#"+divIdIs).length;
    alert(tes);*/
    if(divIdIs == upperDiv){
    alert("Matched");
    }
    else{
    alert("Not Matched");
    }

    //if(divIdIs == existingdivId){}
    //else{}

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
```

replace the above line as below and try

```
if (ids.indexOf("," + ui.draggable[0].id + ",") >= 0)
{
   alert("This div already exists");
   return;
}
ids += ui.draggable[0].id + ",";
```

Also make sure you declare the below variable globally,

```
var ids = ",";
```

Comment: i think it would affect other things too, and what about other things that im doing in drop function what happens to them? let me check and get back to you

Comment: it worked...and i didn't remove the drop:function{ } i place the snippet in the function and its working right..

Comment: sorry.. actually you should add  this line below the drop function. sorry for my typo error.

Comment: there is one problem also, the thing is there are 2 portions where i drop the divs, if i drop the div in one portion and it already exists there then it say the div exists, which is fine, but when i drop the div to the other portion tyhen it also says the div exists, and it shouldn't.. That's why i used  the .prevAll selectors, and here i can't seem to figure it out how should i check only the upper siblings index,, any ideas????

Comment: you can maintain two globalvariables one for div1 and other for div 2.. in that case it will not ovelrap.. fors droppable div1 u can use ids and for droppable div 2 use a new id and store in that. copy the if statement in div1 and paste in div2 drop function and change the id to the new one. that will resolve

Comment: to achieve this you need to change the droppable function a little bit.  the below function is called using classname  $('.droppable').droppable({  change it to use id instead.  so you need to write two function for droppable

Comment: this approach wouldn't be generic you know,,isn't there other way??

Comment: Replace the if statement like below, this concatenated the id of the droppable div along the dropped container.
 if (ids.indexOf("," + $('.droppable').attr("id")+"-"+ui.draggable[0].id + ",") >= 0)
    {
     alert("This div already exists");
     return;
    }
    ids += $('.droppable').attr("id")+"-"+ui.draggable[0].id + ",";

Comment: have you specified id to the two droppable div